# Ionic 2 - other html and css pages for Desktop

Tags: angular, ionic2, cross-platform

I have ionic 2 website app.

This app i used also as website. i.e, when mobile-user is open a browser on the mobile device he can enter to my ionic-2 web-site.

I want to write other css and html pages for Desktop, that will use the same ts files for models and services.

Is there any way to cause Ionic-2-app to load html and css files according to current platform?

For example:

I have the following structure for any page:

[image]

And I want to have the following, instead:

[image]

And I want that when I open my web-site from desktop-browser I will see the login-mobile page, and when I open from desktop I will see the login-desktop page.
**But, notice - that I don't want to lower the speed or performence of my site, so I want to compile each time only the relevant files.**

What is the best way to do that?
Is my idea good or there are other better solutions?